# Redirect in onSubmit() method of simpleformcontroller

Tags: spring, forms, redirect, spring-mvc, onsubmit

I am new to spring framwork and using 2.5 version.
My requirement is that based on some value of command object in submit method I have to redirect the user to url /out.This is not defined as any view.But used for logout.
Ex.
http://127.34.22.22:8080/abc is the invoking url and the url after redirect needed is the http://127.34.22.22:8080/out.
I tried redirect it is working only when I hardcode the whole url,but unable to redirect at runtime.

```
if(attribute is true){
   return new ModelAndView("http://127.34.22.22:8080/out"); 
}else{
   return new ModelAndView(getSuccessView());
}
```

Above  code is working but I don't want to hardcode whole url.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ModelAndView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html) expect an VIEW name but not an URL. (`ModelAndView(String viewName)`)

What you need is to pass an an [RedirectView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html) as parameter to [ModelAndView(View view)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#ModelAndView%28org.springframework.web.servlet.View%29)

Example:

```
if(attribute) {
   return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("http://127.34.22.22:8080/out");
} else {
   ...
}
```